# Get last added to cart product id in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I try all of code from google, but none of them works.

such as:

```
$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
$product_id = end($items)['data']->post->ID;
```

For example,

shoes have two different colors: black and gray.  I added black shoes,  then gray shoes, I order black shoes in the end.

It should return black shoes's ID, but the code on the top will shows gray shoes's id.

I want last added product, not the last position product.

Comment: Use `$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();` and `$product_id = end($items)['data']->get_id();` or `$product_id = end($items)['product_id'];`

Comment: Actually it's different.  I want the last product added to cart's id .   that code only get last position product.  If I added A product, then B product, then A product,  it should shows A's id ,but the result is B.

Comment: I try reset, it would always return A's id, not matter the last product added to cart is A or B.

Comment: I want last added item.

Comment: So for the last item is `$product_id = end($items)['data']->get_id();` or `$product_id = end($items)['product_id'];` … Now **may be your problem is that this is not refreshed** when using **ajax** add to cart. To get that refreshed, it is a new question that you will need to ask, with all related details well explained clearly.

Comment: I need the recently product's id added to cart .   the code is to get last product in the cart.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the products into an array and pick the last one using the php `end()` function as follows:

```
global $woocommerce;

//get cart items
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

$ids = array();
foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
        $_product = $values['data']->post; 
        //push each id into array
        $ids[] = $_product->ID; 
} 

//get last product id
$last_product_id = end($ids);

//get product variation details
$variations = get_variation_data_from_variation_id( $last_product_id );
```

Then define `get_variation_data_from_variation_id($item_id)` as follows:

```
//function to get product variation
    function get_variation_data_from_variation_id( $item_id ) {
        $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $item_id );
        $variation_data = $_product->get_variation_attributes();
        //return variation detail
        return woocommerce_get_formatted_variation( $variation_data, true ); 
    }
```

Comment: First, thanks for answer my question.  And your code have the same result as mine, I added more detail on my question to make it clearer, would you mind take a look again.

Comment: Cool, check the update

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**
I think you were looking for product attribute IDs? Like green or blue etc.

```
$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
$variation = end($cart)['variation'];

// This will have ID, slug, count, etc.
echo json_encode( get_term_by( 'name', end($variation) , str_replace( "attribute_", "", key($variation))) );
```

If you are specific about you attribute like just size change it like this based on your ta

```
$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
$variation = end($cart)['variation']['attribute_pa_size'];

// This will have ID, slug, count, etc.
echo json_encode( get_term_by( 'name', $variation , 'pa_size') );
```

Comment: First, thanks for answer my question.  And your code have the same result as mine, I added more detail on my question to make it clearer, would you mind take a look again.

Comment: @fhgroupauto Please check the edits

Answer (score 0):

That means you probably access the cart Object before It's created, You will need to place that code inside 'wp' hook for example.

```
add_action('wp', function(){
   $product_id = end( WC()->cart->cart_contents)['product_id'];
});
```

Comment: where should I add this. in success.php ? the code I provide in the top is in success.php

Comment: in functions.php

Comment: I added it in functions.php, then I'm unable get $product_id in success.php. DId I miss something?

Comment: sorry, I don't know what success.php is or What do you want to achieve, more info would be helpful.